# "No Join Predicate" when adding an additional condition - why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a, in general, very simple query and don't understand why the actual execution plan shows me a warning "No Join Predicate" right after the initial select on a "Nested Loops" node.

I think the query is pretty self-explanatory: I have Users and they have UserSubscriptions to Feeds (m:n) - I want to query all FeedItems from one Feed the user must be subscribed to, so this query does this very well:

```
select fi.Title, fi.Content, fi.Published
from [User] u 
inner join UserSubscription us on u.id = us.UserId
inner join Feed f on f.id = us.FeedId
inner join FeedItem fi on fi.FeedId = f.Id
where u.EMailAddress = 'xxx@xxx.xx'
and f.id = 3
and fi.Inserted > getdate() - 30
```

The interesting part is that there is no warning as long as i leave out this condition:

```
and f.id = 3
```

As soon as I remove this, the warning about the missing join predicate disappears. I don't understand the cause for this warning here.

Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
b.

Comment: qv http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/should-i-be-alarmed-by-this-no-join-predicate-warning and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35082/what-exactly-does-no-join-predicate-mean-in-sql-server - in short, this isn't *automatically* a bad thing

Comment: Ok as far as I understand - in my case SQL Server would optimize out my Join on Feed as my condition for Feed.Id = 3 makes the join unneccessary? So this is why there's no join predicate for this table anymore? Ok, performance-wise ... that should really not be an issue. Logic-wise I will have to think about that because the Join Feed <-> UserSubscriptions is there to filter for any Feeds the User is really subscribed too as it is not said the User is subscribed to the Feed with ID 3 in this example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't need to JOIN on the Feed table is because:

1. `f.id = us.FeedId = fi.FeedId`
2. The `f` (Feed) table isn't used/necessary anywhere else in the query (`SELECT` or `WHERE`)

Here's a more optimized query:

```
select fi.Title, fi.Content, fi.Published
from [User] u 
inner join UserSubscription us on u.id = us.UserId and us.FeedId = 3
inner join FeedItem fi on fi.FeedId = us.FeedId
where u.EMailAddress = 'xxx@xxx.xx'
and fi.Inserted > getdate() - 30
```

By limiting it to a particular FeedId earlier, you keep your dataset smaller, and therefore faster.  The optimizer *may* change your query to this for you; I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't agree you can eliminate that join.  If Feed has no id of 3 then it would not be in the OP query but it would be in the query you posted.

Comment: @Blam - While true, I feel confident in my assumptions about the schema and constraints of the OP's system based on the original query and the names of its tables.  I do admit there is a chance of the situation you propose.

Comment: Thanks @coge.soft - makes absolute sense. It's likely the Optimizer would remove this Join and it would explain why that causes the "No Join Predicate" warning to pop up. Really interesting stuff.

Thanks to you too, Blam - but coge.soft is right, my schema requires that a Feed with Id = 3 must exist in Feed when such an entry exists in UserSubscription.